# Do anti-glare filters exist for a 24 inch LCD monitor?

Tags: display, brightness, anti-glare

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there effective Anti-glare screens?](https://superuser.com/questions/34327/are-there-effective-anti-glare-screens)

A family member finds a new 24" LCD monitor too bright (painful) to look at even on the lowest brightness/contrast settings.

She has previously had success with an external anti-glare filter but I've been unable to find one large enough to fit this monitor. Do physical filters for larger monitors exist?

Comment: Edited to be specific to physical anti-glare filters for large monitors - is this still a duplicate?

Comment: yes, it is @TomShaw

Comment: @studiohack - The existing questions are about laptop screens and about whether anti-glare filters are effective. My question is about large desktop screens and, assuming filters are effective, whether they come in large sizes. How is this a duplicate?

Comment: the idea is the same. also, it would also be somewhat off-topic as it is a shopping recommendation. Please read the FAQ, linked in the top bar above

Comment: If that's an exact duplicate then I'm Barack Obama. And I guess the shopping clause is the same as the interstate commerce clause: a good excuse for any arbitrary decision. There are plenty of questions that even ask for specific recommendations, which I did not.