# Are there any anti-reflective / anti-glare films or sheets?

Tags: display, crt, anti-glare

It’s really hard to watch videos during the day because light-colored clothing, walls, and such reflect in the (CRT, desktop) monitor.

I’m well aware of screens and such, but is there some sort of film or sheet that can be cut to to the desired dimensions and applied to the screen to reduce/cut reflections? I’m looking for something similar to those sheets that are applied to windows to winterize them; *not* single-sized, snap-on screens like has been given as an answer to the other two or three related questions here.

Comment: Related/Dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/29935/anti-glare-filter-for-glossy-laptop-screen

Comment: @techie007, that is one of the questions that I referred to when I said *[I’m] **not** [looking for] single-sized, snap-on screens like has been given as an answer to the other two or three related questions here*.

Comment: :roll:​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @null I really don’t see how *computer-monitor* anti-glare films are “off topic”. It seems that techie was just offended that I called him on his error.

Comment: You'll note I didn't close it, a mod did.  Takes more than one vote from us 'regular' users.

Comment: You didn’t close it, but you voted to close it and (it at least looks like) you voted so due to a grudge.

Comment: No grudge here. Looked like a dupe to me, that's all.

Comment: Ah okay; I guess you selected *dupe* and for some reason random selected *off topic*. It doesn’t show the reasons given when you hover over the names like it used to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step out of the box, and you find there are multiple products available on the market that are matte finish, adhesive, and come in a roll to allow to be cut to fit.  Everything from [clear shelf paper to automotive "tinting"](http://www.k12schoolsupplies.net/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=PAC72350&click=9&utm_source=google&utm_medium=base&utm_content=gbase_buy&utm_campaign=gbase_Supplies_Contact_Paper&gdftrk=gdfV2544_a_7c642_a_7c6784_a_7cPAC72350).

That is designed to be clear, to allow what is beneath to still be used, while providing protection.  The matte finish would cut down on glare and reflection.  The fact that it is in a roll means you cut it to fit whatever you want.

Comment: But I like my box; it’s so cozy and warm! `:-D` But seriously, that was a great answer. It’s always fun to use things “incorrectly”. It doesn’t look like that specific one is going to be more cost-effective, but I’m sure there are similar ones that are. Now that I know that such things *do* exist, I’ll keep an eye out for something like that next time I’m at the hardware store instead of fruitlessly looking at the computer store.